# Progress bars not displaying information correctly

Tags: php, html, css, progress-bar

My progress bars are always showing 100% that everything is full even when I hover over them its everything is 100/100 this is what I have as of now

energy = 100 & maxenergy = 100(when there full)

right now its energy = 50 & maxenergy = 100(there still showing 100% full)

```css
/*energy bars*/
.bar_a{
    border: 1px solid #4CAf50;
    padding: 2px;
 width: 150px;
    height: 10;
 background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 6px;

}

.bar_b{
 font-size: 10px;
    height: 10;
 background-color: #4CAF50;

}
```

for the php values I have

```
 $is = $db->query("SELECT `u`.*, `us`.* FROM `users` AS `u` INNER JOIN `userstats` AS `us` ON `u`.`userid`=`us`.`userid` WHERE `u`.`userid` = {$userid} LIMIT 1"); $ir = $db->fetch_row($is);

        $enperc = min((int) ($ir['energy'] / $ir['maxenergy'] * 100), 100);
        $enopp = 100 - $enperc;
```

and for the rest of the php as in the bars them self

```
<a title = "Refill Your energy!" href="creditrader?spend=energy"><b>Energy</b></a>
        <div class="bar_a" title="Energy: '.$ir['energy'].'/'.$ir['maxenergy'].' ('.$enperc.'%)">
          <div class="bar_b" style="width: '.$enperc.'%;" title="Energy: '.$ir['energy'].'/'.$ir['maxenergy'].' ('.$enperc.'%)" align="center">'.$ir['energy'].'/'.$ir['maxenergy'].'('.$enperc.'%)</div>
        </div>
```

I have 4 different bars that's one of the 4 and they are all having the same issue one of them are even in the negatives and its still showing 100/100 (100%)

Comment: Could you provide actual values of what your `$ir` array contains? Just `print_r($ir);` and add that to your question.

Comment: The code gives reasonable results (with fitting input) to me.

Comment: UPDATED my bad haha

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the html5 progress element? https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/. I reckon because the number is negative it's being thrown out, replaced by the default width of 100% that a div, a block element, has by default.

Comment: I can't remember why but I had a reason when I first made these and I was going to do them slightly different and as for the negative there, not all negative just the one which I made like that so just for testing it then I noticed none of them where working even when for example energy is only 50 it still does not work.

Comment: May I repeat @IncredibleHat 's question: Could you provide actual values of what your $ir array contains? Just `print_r($ir);` and add that to your question. The sql statement is of no help.

Comment: @Jeff I updated it scroll up to where you see $is then scroll right you will see it. $ir['energy'] pretty much means MY[energy]

Comment: sorry if i am mis understanding anything

Comment: we need the _actual values_. like energy = 512, maxenergy = 1000. In whatever form. easiest would be to show the result of `print_r($ir)`

Comment: ok now i see there is something else causing the issue i have to go through everything when i did print_r($ir) it is saying that energy = 100 and maxenergy = 100 but energy in the database is actually only 50